# C# Task order in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I am currently working at a personal project in c#.

The client is in WPF and connects with a WCF service that saves some data from web (the database is mapped with entity).

So, my problem is at my wcf service.

I am not very pro in c# or multitasking, but I need some guidance before going forward.

The scenario sounds like this:

1. Save from client to WCF.
2. WCF gets the request and initiates the function.
3. Returns a message to client that data will be processed and starts a task that:
4. Downloads data from internet
5. Saves it.

The problem is that the data that I save has an unique id and I check before saving so that data doesn't exists in database.

But, if 2 clients calls simultaneously save function with same data, there will be two tasks that saves info with same id. The id's are the imdbId which are unique.

My idea is that I make a list of tasks and I start a "watcher" that watches over that list and when a client makes a save call, I add the task for saving in the list.

Therefore, the task are ran iterative from the list.

How can I achieve this idea in c#? Data types? Tasks? ThreadPool?

Also, I think that the list must be singleton.

Comment: this should not be a problem, when the id is defined as a pk in the db.
The update would throw an error that u can handle appropriately.
Not sure I got u right.

Comment: well, save two entities with same pk and will get an exception from the database. that's why is a pk, to be unique.

Comment: and what is your problem, this is normal behavior, just handle the specific exception.

Comment: it happens that I have to save 250 info at once. In entity I won't make commit (SaveChanges) after every add, it's suicidal. Therefore, I load the last context, add the current data after checking if exists and then commit all changes. Starting a task to do that means that two tasks will save at the same time(perhaps) two movies with same imdbId.

Comment: Why are the clients telling you what the PK is? They should be handling the data, not how you uniquely identify it. Is there a reason they have to send in the PK?

Comment: the primary key is generated when the movies is saved. but I have an index on movieId which must be unique. the client doesn't sends data that the database will handle. I think you're focusing on my model and not task related question.

Comment: can't you use a GUID as PK?